# UVC function config interface

Tags: linux, usb, uvc

I'm reading [Linux Documentation about UVC function](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L660). I'm struggling to understand an example that [starts here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L695) and goes [until here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L714). What exactly is this going to do and where exactly do I create these files?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a better link that won't break and only needs one URL: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0993133bb8e7a75524748ffed52c62e81c42b3e8/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L695-L714

Answer (score 0):

From your other posts I gather that you are attempting to implement a UVC gadget with a Xilinx device. Nonetheless, as Linux devices share the same opaque kernel documentation, the procedure is just as error-prone on the Raspberry Pi Zero and other OTG-enabled devices.

> What exactly is this going to do

The idea of a UVC gadget is to build something that acts like a webcam. Once completed you could potentially connect that device into a Mac or PC and use it as your video for FaceTime or Skype.

Depending on your goals you could stream synthetic images, a recorded video, or passthrough video from an add-on like a MIPI CSI camera.

> where exactly do I create these files?

Here's a great intro to ConfigFS: [link](http://irq5.io/2016/12/22/raspberry-pi-zero-as-multiple-usb-gadgets/). Again it's for Raspberry Pi Zero rather than your Xilinx device, but the same concepts apply.

While gadget-testing.txt is inconveniently curt, if you start off by running:

```
 modprobe libcomposite
 cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
```

then you can proceed with the steps `mkdir functions/uvc.usb0/control/header/h` ...

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51243/how-do-you-configure-the-pi-zero-to-act-as-a-usb-webcam-using-the-plug-in-camera) is a more detailed post covering various caveats on Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange.